# CKEditor 5: How to use Mentions in Comments?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

How to use **CKeditor** mentions feed element in **Ckeditor** comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the below sample to check how to add the Mention plugin to the comment editor:

```
const extraCommentsPlugins = ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins.filter(
    plugin => [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Mention' ].includes( plugin.pluginName );
);

ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        toolbar: {
            items: [ 'bold', 'italic', '|', 'comment' ]
        },
        sidebar: {
            container: document.querySelector( '#sidebar' )
        },
        comments: {
            editorConfig: {
                extraPlugins: extraCommentsPlugins,
                mention: {
                    feeds: [
                        {
                            marker: '@',
                            feed: [
                                '@NICK', '@NOHEA',
                                '@REATHEON', '@FIRE FOX', '@NORMSA'
                            ],
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    } )
    .catch( error => console.error( error ) );
```